# how to map multiple table in to one table - hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have three table **topic**, **query**, **response** and I need another table **topic_query_response_map**. I don't want to update those three tables during **insert**, **update**, **delete** operation of **topic_query_response_map**.

[image]

If it is possible using hibernate, then how **topic_query_response_map** entity class will look like?

Comment: What about using a view in the SQL database itself?

Comment: Why don't you want to create the `topic_query_response_map` table in the database?

Comment: Because I am using hibernate, and I want everything to be created and maintained by hibernate